# $(1+x+...+x^{2n})^{\frac{1}{2n}}$ is convex?

Tags: calculus

For natural number $n$, Let $f_n=(1+x+...+x^{2n})^{\frac{1}{2n}}$.  Then I think that $f_n$ is convex. Is it true? And how to I prove that? I tried to prove that $f_n''>0$. But i cannot to prove that.

Comment: Can you clarify what the domain of the function is? It seems to be more difficult to prove the convexity for negative $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the identity $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^k = \dfrac {x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}$ to rewrite the function and take the second derivative. To prove $f''(x) \ge 0$, you will need to prove that $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^k \ge 0$ for all $x$ if $k$ is even.